# Are any of the characters featured in this scene aware of what the audience experiences?

Tags: plot-explanation, hannibal

In the third episode of the third season of the TV series [Hannibal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_(TV_series)), titled "Secendo", there is a scene that starts about 35 minutes into the episode, where after Will Graham lets Hannibal's captive loose, he attacks Chiyoh and seems to have killed her. But just then time begins to move in reverse and deviates back to a point where Chiyoh now kills the captive instead.

Just to clarify *time in reverse* is important concept in at least two ways to the story:

1. The possibility of such a phenomenon is what Hannibal Lecter uses as a measurement to make certain decisions, as it also is a method one could use in determining possible outcomes (Many World Interpretation Theory/Schrodinger's Cat).
2. This happens to be the way Will Graham thinks and/or comes to investigate crime scenes (along with evidence) to make certain "leaps". (This is also why Hannibal finds himself enamored with Will Graham.)

My question is, ***are any of the characters in this scene (Will Graham, Chiyoh, or the Captive) aware of seeing the two different outcomes or is this solely for the audiences' benefit?***

In other words, whose perspective was this phenomenon being experienced by?

---

Note: I can imagine that Will Graham would be a likely candidate of whose perspective it was from, given this is how he experiences things and because he let the prisoner/captive free.

However, the scene does not start with Will inspecting a situation, which is normally how Will's mind works; **after the fact and not before it**.

Instead it starts with Chiyoh approaching the prisoner, he assaults and kills her, time moves in reverse, then she kills him; she says she's sorry and then screams, before Will Graham enters the dungeon.

Maybe Will is now able to do what Hannibal does and this was a reflection of that, but I still would like some clarification either from dialogue of the characters in later episodes or the executive producers/cast, *if there is any*.